# Source not found error , even though correct dependency defined

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on an RCP app , where plugin A has dependency for plugin B . Plugin A calls a method getCodes() which is defined in plugin B . Plugin A's POM has 4.1.1-SNAPSHOT version defined , which is the version for plugin B .

While debugging , the execution flow doesnt go to plugin B . Instead i get the following error

```
source not found 
edit source look up path
```

I ran mvn eclipse clean command but i still get the error , could any one suggest what could be the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Does the library for plugin B have any defined link to its source?

Comment: The issue has been resolved , i installed the plugin B in the local repo and it worked . Thanks for help